# Creating a 3 category binned colormap for continuous variable for matplotlib plot?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have two measurements x & y and one calculation f(x, y) where f(x, y) can be broken into 3 categories: Acceptable(>1.2), At Risk (1 < x <=1.2), and Not Acceptable (<=1). I was wondering what is the best way to bin and plot this where f(x,y) is the colormap for a y v x scatter plot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are after but sounds like you might be interested in [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html)